# Is this patent on a rudder innertube still valid?

Tags: patent-lifetime

In reference to the patent: [US6182594](https://www.google.com/patents/US6182594)

Is this patent still valid ?

Jeff

Answer (score 1):

US6192594 was filed on Oct. 12th, 1999 and should expire 20 years from that date assuming all fees are kept up to date. The best site to confirm the status of US patents is the [US Public Pair](https://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair). I checked and the fees are paid and up to date so the patent should expire on Oct. 12th, 2019.